# Aggregating non-unique IEnumerable Selects

Tags: c#, data-structures, ienumerable

I have the following statement:

```
        List<Tuple<string, string>> content = new List<Tuple<string, string>>()
        {
            new Tuple<string, string>("Source", "Source Table"),
            new Tuple<string, string>(COLUMN_HEADER_UNDERLINE, COLUMN_HEADER_UNDERLINE)
        }            
        .Union(_project.Sources
            .Where(source=>source.SourceTables.Count ==0)
            .Select(source=> new Tuple <string,string> (source.DisplayText,"<NONE>")))
            .ToList()
```

This results, in an example instance, into the following when I have 2 data sources in _project.Sources which are identical:

```
Source              Source Table 
------------        ------------   
Profile.xls         <NONE>
```

My desired result is:

```
Source              Source Table 
------------        ------------   
Profile.xls         <NONE>       
Profile.xls         <NONE>
```

How can I change my IEnumerable to select non-unique, identical data sources?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Documentation exists, and often has the answer. The documentation for [Enumerable.Union](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731(v=vs.110).aspx) says: "This method excludes duplicates from the return set. This is different behavior to the Concat<TSource> method, which returns all the elements in the input sequences including duplicates."

Comment: Solved by the explanation provided by @Jim Thank you for the initial comment, as well Rob